# extjs4 autoLoad for render html page is not working ?

Tags: extjs, extjs4

this code working in extjs 3 but now i convet my  app to extjs 4 its not working give any solution

```
var invent_el = Ext.getCmp('tabcon');    
var tab = invent_el.getItem('tab_Transfer');
if(tab)
{
     tab.show();
}else{
     invent_el.add({
         title    : 'Transfer Stock',
         html     : 'This is Order Tab...',
         activeTab: 0,
         closable : true ,
         id: 'tab_Transfer',
         autoLoad:{url:'/reorder_details',scripts:true}
    }).show();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe Transfer Stock is a tab panel, and in extjs 4 the tab panel does not have a autoLoad configuration.
Replace the autoload config with a loader

```
loader: {
        url: '/reorder_details',
        scripts: true,
        autoLoad: true
}
```

Comment: also check the render attribute - which changes how the fetched data is interpreted: http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.ElementLoader-cfg-renderer